# Get all pairs from elements in sublists

Tags: python

I have a list of sublists. I need all possible pairs between the elements in the sublists. For example, for a list like this:

```
a=[[1,2,3],[4,5],[6]]
```

The result should be:

```
result=[[1,4], [1,5], [1,6], 
        [2,4], [2,5], [2,6], 
        [3,4], [3,5], [3,6], 
        [4,6], [5,6]]
```

The lists (and sublists) are of various, random lengths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> a=[[1,2,3],[4,5],[6]]
>>> b=[]
>>> for index, item in enumerate(a):
...    b.extend([[i, j] for i in item for j in chain.from_iterable(a[index+1:])])
>>> b
[[1, 4],
 [1, 5],
 [1, 6],
 [2, 4],
 [2, 5],
 [2, 6],
 [3, 4],
 [3, 5],
 [3, 6],
 [4, 6],
 [5, 6]]
```

Comment: Thank you, this is fast and easy, and it returns the result exactly as needed.

Answer (score 1):

```
from itertools import chain, product, combinations

sublists = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [6]]
pairs = chain.from_iterable(
    product(*sublist_pair) for sublist_pair in combinations(sublists, 2)
)
for x, y in pairs:
    print(x, y)
```

Comment: Thank you! This works well but the other method is slightly faster.

Answer (score 0):

```
# create an empty set to store unique sublist elements
initSet = set()

# combine all sublist elements
for sublist in a:
    tempSet = set(sublist)
    initSet = intiSet.union(tempSet)

initSet = list(initSet)
# find all possible non-repeating combinations
for _element in initSet:
    combinations = list()
    for i in range(1, len(initSet) - 1):
        combinations.append([_element, initSet[i]]
    initSet.pop(0)

#result stored in combinations
```