# iItertools.product with variable validation

Tags: python, list, dictionary, python-itertools

I have this form of list

```
data = [
   [
    {'name': 's11', 'class': 'c1'}, {'name': 's12', 'class': 'c2'}
   ],
   [
    {'name': 's21', 'class': 'c2'}, {'name': 's22', 'class': 'c2'}
   ],
   [
    {'name': 's31', 'class': 'c1'}, {'name': 's32', 'class': 'c1'}
   ]
]
```

by using the `itertools.product(data)`
I receive all the possible combinations needed by taking one element from each list in the main list data.
What I want to do, I want to skip if the element in the first sublist have a different class in the second or third sublist.

Does itertools.product provide any validation options for such case ?

The expected results should be:

```
({'name': 's11', 'class': 'c1'},{'name': 's31', 'class': 'c1'}),
( {'name': 's11', 'class': 'c1'}, {'name': 's32', 'class': 'c1'}),
({'name': 's12', 'class': 'c2'},{'name': 's21', 'class': 'c2'}),
({'name': 's12', 'class': 'c2'},{'name': 's22', 'class': 'c2'}),
```

Comment: No, it doesn't.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga is there any other possible way to do so

Comment: @f0unix please add to the question a result you want to get.

Comment: @skovorodkin I have just added it

Answer (score 0):

```
from itertools import chain, combinations, product
result = [
    (a, b) for a, b 
    in chain.from_iterable(product(*l) for l in combinations(data, 2)) 
    if a['class'] == b['class']
]
```

Comment: So this answer is really close to my other post [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39835618/847552), you just need to filter out unwanted elements.

Answer (score 0):

Almost the same as @skovorodkin posted.

```
from itertools import product, chain

data = [
    [{'name': 's11', 'class': 'c1'}, {'name': 's12', 'class': 'c2'}],
    [{'name': 's21', 'class': 'c2'}, {'name': 's22', 'class': 'c2'}],
    [{'name': 's31', 'class': 'c1'}, {'name': 's32', 'class': 'c1'}]
]
output = [i for i in product(data[0], chain.from_iterable(data[1:])) if i[0]['class'] == i[1]['class']]
output
```

Output:

```
[({'class': 'c1', 'name': 's11'}, {'class': 'c1', 'name': 's31'}),
 ({'class': 'c1', 'name': 's11'}, {'class': 'c1', 'name': 's32'}),
 ({'class': 'c2', 'name': 's12'}, {'class': 'c2', 'name': 's21'}),
 ({'class': 'c2', 'name': 's12'}, {'class': 'c2', 'name': 's22'})]
```

**UPDATE**

Just a little comparison. I just used the default data and the time results are the following:

@skovorodkin answer:

```
>>> %timeit result = [(a, b) for a, b in chain.from_iterable(product(*l) for l in combinations(data, 2)) if a['class'] == b['class']]
The slowest run took 8.56 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
100000 loops, best of 3: 3.69 µs per loop
```

My answer:

```
>>> %timeit output = [i for i in product(data[0], chain.from_iterable(data[1:])) if i[0]['class'] == i[1]['class']]
The slowest run took 10.37 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.43 µs per loop
```